# Homomorphism and image

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

I'll consider the function $\phi: \mathbb Z^3 \to \mathbb Z^3$, given by:

$\phi(x,y,z) := (x+5y+3z,2y,7z)$

I have a couple of questions associated with this:

1) This might be a very dumb question, but if I wanted to show, that this is an homomorphism, I'll just follow the standard approach, but am I able to just add the 5y with the 2y etc. or how should I interpret the commas?:

I'll say that x,y,z,a,b,c are all elements of the integers.
Then:

$\phi(x,y,z,a,b,c)=\phi(x+a,y+b,z+c)=x+a)+5(y+b)+2(y+b)+3(x+c)+7(x+c)=(x+a)+7(y+b)+10(z+c)=(x+7y+10z)+(a+7b+10c)=\phi(x,y,x)+\phi(a,b,c)$

It is thereby an homomorphism.

So my question here is simply if I'm allowed to do this or how else I should interpret the commas in the function?

2) Secondly, I'll have that the image of $\phi(\mathbb Z^3)$ is just $\mathrm{Im}\ \phi(\mathbb Z^3) = \{\phi(x,y,z) : x,y,z \text{ being elements of }\mathbb Z^3\}$ (right?), but how would I go about finding the number of elements in $\mathbb Z^3/\phi(\mathbb Z^3)$?

3) Last, but not least, I was wondering; What possibilities are there generally for the structure of the image for a homomorphism: $\psi: \mathbb Z^3 \to \mathbb Z^3$?

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  To interpret the commas:  note the homomorphism is defined on triplets of elements of Z, and commas separate the elements

Comment: Are you considering $Z^3$ to be a group with component-wise addition?

Comment: Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The function $\phi$ is a function with three variables, not six, and therefore the expression $\phi(x,y,z,a,b,c))$ makes no sense. What you are supposed to prove is that$$\bigl(\forall(x,y,z),(a,b,c)\in\mathbb Z^3\bigr):\phi\bigl((x,y,z)+(a,b,c)\bigr)=\phi(x,y,z)+\phi(a,b,c).$$
2. Yes, $\operatorname{Im}\phi=\bigl\{\phi(x,y,z)\,|\,(x,y,z)\in\mathbb Z^3\bigr\}$, but the idea is to determine this set explicitely. For instance, if $(a,b,c)\in\operatorname{Im}\phi$, then $7\mid c$. *After* you have determined $\operatorname{Im}\phi$ explicitely, *then* you can try to comput $\mathbb Z^3/\operatorname{Im}\phi$.
3. There are several possibilites, such has $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Z^2$, $\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z$, and so on.

Comment: Thank you. It in the second question, it makes sense that I need to determine the set explicitely before I can find the number of elements, but I'm not sure how to approach doing that. I can see why 7 | c, 2 | b etc., but how does that lead me to the set?

Comment: It turns out that $\operatorname{Im}\phi=\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb Z^3\,|\,2\mid b\wedge7\mid c\}$. It is not hard to deduce from this that $\mathbb Z^3/\operatorname{Im}\phi\simeq\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_7$.